# Switching from Procedural to OOP PHP using Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I'm finally making the switch to OOP from procedural and starting with CodeIgniter and just looking for clarification. For every page that you would typically have (about.php) will you have both a view (about.php) and a controller (About.php) for every page? I'm trying to wrap my head around it and I've always given up and went back to procedural and now I'm forcing myself to learn object oriented.

Comment: Why is that must better, when you have an index file with a bunc of `switch / case` about `switch ($action) { case "about": include('about.php'); break } //....` ? OOP and MVC is really great thing if you understand. Much more easier to use, there are a lot of advantages, views are separated from business logic, classes are reusables, etc... Codeigniter a light-weight and good framework. Once you learn that, you will facepalm "How can i live without this?"

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly one way you could do it, but it doesn't have to be that way.

In CodeIgniter, your controller forms a section of your site, and looks in most URLs like a sub-folder, e.g.

```
http://example.net/products/tvs
```

There, products is the name of a controller, and tvs - in URL terms, the sub-page - is a method of that controller.

So yes, you could have a controller for each page, but no, you normally wouldn't. Think instead of controllers being responsible for site sections rather than individual pages.

Comment: If you strip away the controller layer, you could say you subscribe functions to url paths, as opposed to have an all seeing all knowing front controller routing the requests.

Answer (score 0):

The controller controls everything, you could have all your info in a DB, but if you want to have actual files, then put them in your "view" folder and just add a function in your controller.

Something like this:

**controller:**
function about_us_page() {// load your about_us.php view file here}

**view:**
about_us.php

and you should link to it like:
example.com/controller/about_us.php